# CSS - Deal With Margin And Padding On Top Of Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I am trying to get rid of the top area of a page completely, using CSS:

[image]

I have the following CSS, pieced together from articles, which gets rid of everything:

```
<style type='text/css'>
#titleAreaBox #SearchBox {display: none !important;}
.ms-siteicon-img{Display:none !Important;} 
.ms-core-pageTitle{Display:none !Important;} 
.ms-core-navigation { display: none !important;}#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }
#titleAreaBox{margin: 0px; display: none !important;}
</style>
```

however there are large gaps still on the top of the site. The content starts under the blue line:

[image]

How to get rid of the top area with CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browser you are using, download the developer toolbar.
With this toolbar you can easily inspect the HTML / CSS code and play around with the settings. While changing CSS parameters you will see the changes.

It's hard to point the problem exactly since there is no code shown. But it will probably some margin / padding / border / line-height / height property problem.

Have a look with a developer toolbar to find the cause of the problem.